# State Not Updating in React Functional Component

Tags: reactjs, components, state

I'm encountering an issue with updating state in my React functional component. I have a simple component where I'm trying to toggle a boolean state (isOpen) when a button is clicked. However, the state doesn't seem to update properly when the button is clicked.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

function MyComponent() {
    const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);

    const toggleOpen = () => {
        setIsOpen(!isOpen);
        console.log(isOpen); // This still logs the previous state value
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={toggleOpen}>
                {isOpen ? 'Close' : 'Open'}
            </button>
           {isOpen && <p>Content to show when open</p>}
        </div>
    );
}

export default MyComponent;
```

When I click the button, the state isOpen should toggle between true and false, and the content should show or hide accordingly. However, even though setIsOpen(!isOpen) is called, the console.log(isOpen) statement still logs the previous state value. As a result, the UI doesn't update correctly.

Comment: The state is changing, you just have a log statement that isn't useful. `isOpen` is a local `const` which is a snapshot of what the state was when the component rendered. calling `setIsOpen` does not change your local variables, instead it asks react to rerender the component. When that render happens, a new local variable will be made with a new snapshot, but code from your last render has no access to future local variables.

Comment: If you'd like to verify that the component rerenders with a new value, i'd suggest putting the log statement in the body of the component. Eg, on the line right after you call `useState`

Comment: The useState hook is not synchronous, so, you can not see the updated value if you execute the console log just after the set.

For that you need to use the useEffect hook